# Using TestNG, is it possible to dynamically change the test name?

Tags: junit, testng

Using TestNG, is it possible to dynamically change the test name with a method such as this one below?

```
@Test(testName = "defaultName", dataProvider="tests")
public void testLogin( int num, String reportName )
{
    System.out.println("Starting " + num + ": " + reportName);
    changeTestName("Test" + num);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but your test class can implement `org.testng.ITest` and override getTestName() to return the name of your test.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I might be able to set the test name from input coming from the DataProvider.  I'll think about it now that I know its not straight forward.

Comment: @Cedric I've tried using ITest, but the name does not change in the HTML report that gets generated, nor does it changes in the TestNG Eclipse plugin GUI. where am i going wrong public class TestNGNameTest implements ITest
{
 Test
 public void test(ITestContext context)
 {
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
  System.out.println("Test name : "+context.getName());
 }
 Override
 public String getTestName()
 {
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
  return "testOverridenName";
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

For anybody still facing this.
This can be done by implementing the `org.testng.ITest` class and overriding the getTestName() method just like as @Cedric mentions. 

To make the test name dynamic you can use a locally created `testName` variable In addition. 
Below is all you need to do

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.ITest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class MyTestClass implements ITest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "/* yourDataProvider */")
    public void myTestMethod() {
        //Test method body
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setTestName(Method method, Object[] row) {
        //You have the test data received through dataProvider delivered here in row
        String name = resolveTestName(row);
        testName.set(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return testName.get();
    }
    private ThreadLocal<String> testName = new ThreadLocal<>();
}
```

This way you should be able to generate the testName dynamically

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.     Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the error below, about the two parameters of BeforeMethod, what is wrong?

Message:

org.testng.TestNGException:
Method initLog requires 2 parameters but 2 were supplied in the BeforeMethod annotation.

```
    @Parameters({"method", "FinancialKeys"})
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void initLog(Method method, Object[] FinancialKeys) {...}
```

Comment: Im guessing that commenting out that `Parameters` annotation might fix it.