# Change method annotation parameter values

Tags: java, reflection, testng

I am trying to change the test parameter description on run time. All the examples I have seen refers to changing annotation value at class level. But, I want to do it at method level.

My sample code is as below:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestClass {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method method){
        Test annotation = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
        // I want to change description to "some modified description"
    }

    @Test(description = "some description")
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("in test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: why do you want to change the description at runtime instead of rewriting it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Annotation parameters cannot be changed because they have to be known at compile-time.

You could use an interface with a getter and setter instead of an annotation if you need to change it.

With TestNG, you can implement `ITest` and overwrite the method `getTestName()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12148634/10871900) describes.

Comment: Can I add an annotation by myself at runtime then? I want to add it during runtime so that I can change description when using multiple data using data provider.

Comment: No, annotations must be known at compile time.

Comment: nah, nothing needs to be known at compile time, just doing it is a very poor and bad idea but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733914/how-i-can-change-method-annotations-value-in-runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime?noredirect=1&lq=1